# How to make GWT Super Dev Mode work on a GWT element inside HTML iframe?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I have a large application and one of the part of it has a GWT application inside HTML iframe on a page. When I try to run the Super Dev mode on this page, the CodeServer returns a message box saying no GWT module found. Whereas if I go to the application inside the iframe separately, the Super Dev Mode works perfectly. Is there a way to make Super Dev Mode work on the iframe element right inside my application without opening it up separately.

Comment: You need to "hack" the bookmarklet by changing target of the magic javascript code contained in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@luigi-polvani yes, I found a solution on the lines of what you said.

```
javascript:{      
    window.__gwt_bookmarklet_params = {'server_url':'http://localhost:9876/'}; 
    var s = document.createElement('script');      
    s.src ='http://localhost:9876/dev_mode_on.js';      
    void(document.getElementsByTagName('iframe[0]').contentWindow
         .document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s));     
 }
```